# Group documents with same value, and get document with max value for every group

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a similar mongodb collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "item1", "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "item2", "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "item2", "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "item1", "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "item2", "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z") }
```

I want to get the latest document (based on **date** value) for every **item**

Means I want a query/aggregation to give me:

```
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "item1", "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "item2", "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z") }
```

Comment: Please read [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: @jabaa I can't argue with you, but in fact I did some failed tries but too stupid to be shared

Comment: In that case this question is off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `$sort` by `date` in descending order
- `$group` by `item` and get the first root document
- `$replaceRoot` to replace root document object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",
      root: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DVmaIgSEBCB)

Comment: how "expensive" (time) is this grouping, if you have more than 3million documents?

Comment: it could be expensive, in this case, you can use the compound index in `date` and `item` field, second if you don't want to trouble this query and really need quick response you can create a separate collection and manage/save/update the last version item wise everytime when new version arrives.